# How to scroll horizontally, in a vertical scrollable ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, vertical-scrolling, scrollable

so i want to scroll horizontally and this horizontal widget are also should be able to be scrolled with the whole screen vertically

i get errors while using the horizontal ListView in a parent vertical ListView

Comment: kindly, add your code which you have tried.

Comment: add your code then we will be able to understand and help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below property in Listview :

```
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
ListView(
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: 70, // Height of horizontal list view.
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: const [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Text("some Widgets"),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Text("some Widgets"),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Text("some Widgets"),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Text("some Widgets"),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Text("some Widgets"),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Text("some Widgets"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```